# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. creating a view error

Tags: sql, select, view

I am creating a view for a database for an assignment,

i keep getting this error in my code though.

```
CREATE VIEW Rental_View

SELECT Mo.Movie_ID, copy_id, mo.Movie_Name, format_name
FROM Movies AS mo JOIN copies AS co
ON mo.Movie_ID = co.movie_id  
JOIN format AS fo
ON co.Format_id = fo.format_id

SELECT c.customer_id, rental_ID, DATEDIFF (day, rental_date, return_date) AS  rental_duration' , c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name AS customer_name
FROM Customers AS c INNER JOIN rentals AS r
ON c.customer_ID = r.customer_ID
```

In the first SELECT statement it is underlined red and i get the error

"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'."

i literally have no idea how to correct this as i am fairly new to SQL, any help would be much appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The first `SELECT` is to define the `VIEW`. What is the second for?

Comment: i didn't know that you couldn't have two SELECT statements, how can i make it so that i can have all of the above code in one VIEW statement?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the **`AS`** keyword:

```
CREATE VIEW Rental_View   AS            --- <------ AS needed here

SELECT mo.Movie_ID                     --- mo, not Mo
     , co.copy_id                      --- play safe and declare which table 
     , mo.Movie_Name
     , fo.format_name                  --- are these two columns from
FROM Movies AS mo JOIN copies AS co
ON mo.Movie_ID = co.movie_id  
JOIN format AS fo
ON co.Format_id = fo.format_id  
;                                     --- add a ; if you want to
                                      --- run multiple statements
```

---

If you want to combine the two `SELECT` in one, you need to `JOIN` the tables from both, with something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW Rental_View   AS           

SELECT mo.Movie_ID                     
     , co.copy_id                      
     , mo.Movie_Name
     , fo.format_name                  
     , c.customer_id
     , rental_ID
     , DATEDIFF (day, rental_date, return_date) AS rental_duration 
     , c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name AS customer_name
FROM Movies AS mo 
  JOIN copies AS co
    ON mo.Movie_ID = co.movie_id  
  JOIN format AS fo
    ON co.Format_id = fo.format_id  

  JOIN rentals AS r
    ON r.movie_id = mo.Movie_id        --- just a guess, you have to write this
  JOIN Customers AS c 
    ON c.customer_ID = r.customer_ID
```

Comment: Tried that already, i then get a syntax error in 

"CREATE VIEW Rental_view" as an incorrect syntax

Comment: Then, you have to tell us what the second select is for. Is it related with the View? Try running the two code parts separately.

Comment: okay, i have fixed all of the above that you mentioned, although i still now get a syntax error along the top line

"CREATE VIEW Rental_View AS"

all underlined in red with a syntax error, 

also have i got the Second select statement in the correct place? can you even have a second SELECT statement in a VIEW statement.


The second view is related the the first one, was wondering if i can include them all in the one statement...

or would it be easier to create another view instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW Rental_View
AS
```

you are missing the "AS" keyword

Answer (score 0):

You look top have an erroneous single quote after `rental_duration` in this code -

```
SELECT c.customer_id, rental_ID, DATEDIFF (day, rental_date, return_date) AS  rental_duration' , c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name AS customer_name
FROM Customers AS c INNER JOIN rentals AS r
ON c.customer_ID = r.customer_ID
```

try

```
SELECT c.customer_id, rental_ID, DATEDIFF (day, rental_date, return_date) AS  rental_duration , c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name AS customer_name
FROM Customers AS c INNER JOIN rentals AS r
ON c.customer_ID = r.customer_ID
```

Comment: thanks, didn't see that one, although this doesn't help me with the first SELECT statement...not sure what the incorrect syntax is in the second line?

    SELECT Mo.Movie_ID, copy_id, mo.Movie_Name, format_name

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing the first select from

SELECT **Mo.Movie_ID**, copy_id, mo.Movie_Name, format_name

to

SELECT **mo.Movie_ID**, copy_id, mo.Movie_Name, format_name

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in the code that you have posted.

1. The CREATE VIEW statement needs AS keyword befor the SELECE statement. You might do it like:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW Rental_View
   AS
   SELECT Mo.Movie_ID, copy_id, mo.Movie_Name, format_name
   FROM Movies AS mo JOIN copies AS co
   ON mo.Movie_ID = co.movie_id  
   JOIN format AS fo
   ON co.Format_id = fo.format_id
   ```
2. And I could see another SELECT statement, that is making no meaning in a view. Adding the second SELECT statement will cause an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'." for the second SELECT statement.

Comment: so you are saying that i should not include two SELECT statements in the one VIEW statement?

Comment: Yes, without this you will get an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'." for the second SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CREATE VIEW Rental_View
AS
  SELECT Mo.Movie_ID, copy_id, mo.Movie_Name, format_name
  FROM Movies AS mo JOIN copies AS co
  ON mo.Movie_ID = co.movie_id  
  JOIN format AS fo
  ON co.Format_id = fo.format_id

CREATE VIEW Rental_Duration
AS
      SELECT c.customer_id, rental_ID, DATEDIFF (day, rental_date, return_date) AS  rental_duration , c.first_name +   ' ' + c.last_name AS customer_name
      FROM Customers AS c INNER JOIN rentals AS r
     ON c.customer_ID = r.customer_ID
```

Normally you don't create a view that will return more than one result set. If this is truly what you desire then a BEGIN/END block should solve the problem (Untested - not  infront of any RDMS right now):

```
CREATE VIEW Rental_View
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT Mo.Movie_ID, copy_id, mo.Movie_Name, format_name
  FROM Movies AS mo JOIN copies AS co
  ON mo.Movie_ID = co.movie_id  
  JOIN format AS fo
  ON co.Format_id = fo.format_id

  SELECT c.customer_id, rental_ID, DATEDIFF (day, rental_date, return_date) AS  rental_duration , c.first_name +   ' ' + c.last_name AS customer_name
      FROM Customers AS c INNER JOIN rentals AS r
     ON c.customer_ID = r.customer_ID
END
```

Comment: Tried that and i get a syntax error with BEGIN. :/ it might be easier for me to create two views? I'll try your first method. thanks.

Comment: I just fixed my error. a simple GO in between On and SELECT with the addition of AS in the first part of my statement fixed the whole thing.

Comment: also, the addition of a second view statement also worked, but with a bit more fiddling. thankyou!

Comment: @Wayne: You can not include two SELECT statements in a single View.